# Error creating new repository (PERMISSION_DENIED)

Tags: google-cloud-source-repos

I have a problem creating a new repository in Cloud Source Repository (console or gcloud).

In the gcloud case, when I run the following command using either an user account with **roles/owner** or a service account with **roles/source.admin**:

```
gcloud source repos create new-repo
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.create) ResponseError:
> status=[PERMISSION_DENIED], code=[403], message=[User [xxx@xxx] does
> not have permission to access projects instance [PROJECT_ID] (or it
> may not exist): The caller does not have permission].

The project currently has no repositories associated to it. I was able to create one earlier (through the console) which I then deleted before using. I have been unable to create any subsequent repositories since.

Would love to hear some suggestions if anyone else has faced a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned to have the proper roles on the account this issue is due to not having a billing account linked to the project.

The API methods used to create a repository require the billing on the project to be enabled so to solve it if this is the issue you can perform the following [steps](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#enable_billing_for_an_existing_project)

- Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/billing
- Select the project where you want the repository to reside
- Click on **Link a Billing Account**
- A Popup message will show, over there click on **Create Billing Account**
- Follow the wizard

Comment: The project has a billing account linked to it so that's not what's causing this.

Comment: if after making sure the project has a valid Billing Account the issue continues I suggest to open a support ticket with Google Cloud Plattform using the following [link](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/prod_issue)